# Use of the <<- operator in R

Tags: r, statistics

I understand from online sources that the "<<-" operator in R is used to assign a value to a variable in some other environment. This is a little vague and there seems to be no good documentation explaining the exact behavior of this operator as compared to the assignment (<-) operator in R. Any pointers (pun intended)?

Comment: IMHO `?assignOps` is pretty good